# Solr 4.0 default distance unit

Tags: solr, distance

From solr wiki, it seems that the default distance unit specified in 'd' query param is in 'km' (kilometer)

However based on my testing, it seems like it defaults to 'degree'

```
start:0
rows:100
wt:json
indent:true    
fq:{!geofilt sfield=location}    
pt:-32.058333,122.050000
d:0.01
```

How can I make sure that the distance unit is indeed degree (or km) ?

Answer (score 0):

To use kilometers as distance unit, use solr.LatLonType

I was using solr.PointType earlier, which has a distance unit of a degree (i assume).